# vertical align middle divs with float right & left

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a user name and photograph that appears side by side and middle aligned, as shown below.

[image]

I am now trying to change the css so that the photo is dynamically floated to the left and the user name is dynamically floated to the right.

I have tried adding float: right and float left to the css but this only makes the photograph appear under the user name.

I have read several similar threads and tried many things, but I cannot solve this. It is really frustrating. It may be a simple fix, but I cannot see it.

**Using CSS, how do I display the username on the right and the photo on the left and still have the user name and photo vertical-align: middle with a width of 100%? The photo that the user uploads can be different height, so I cannot use line-height.**

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="resumeStyleResumeTitleWrapper17">
    <div class="resumeStyleResumeTitle17">
        <div class="resumeStyleResumeTitleInner17">
            <div class="resumeStyleResumeTitleFontChange17">User Name</div>
        </div>
        <div class="resumeStyleResumeTitlePhotograph17">
            <div class="resumeStyleResumeTitlePhotographInner17">
                {# image has max-height: 149px & max-width: 149px; assigned in the css file #}
                <img class="name_details_photograph_preview_dimensions" src="{{ image_url }}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css code:

```
.resumeStyleResumeTitleWrapper17 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}

.resumeStyleResumeTitle17 {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    direction: ltr;
    display: table-cell;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.resumeStyleResumeTitleInner17 {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    direction: ltr;
    display: table-cell;
    max-height: 149px;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}

.resumeStyleResumeTitleFontChange17 {
    direction: ltr;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
}

.resumeStyleResumeTitlePhotograph17 {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    direction: ltr;
    display: table-cell;
    max-height: 149px;
    max-width: 149px;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.resumeStyleResumeTitlePhotographInner17 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.name_details_photograph_preview_dimensions {
    max-height: 149px;
    max-width: 149px;
}
```

Comment: Man, this is usually easy to achieve, but your html structure really sucks.

Comment: connexo, what are the changes I have to make?

Comment: Actually, I have to apologize. Currently I am even convinced that this is not possible, as easy as it may sound.

Comment: Are you able to modify the HTML? Is it a requirement to use floats? If not, something like this is a lot simpler and seems to do what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/Ltxjjd4k/1/

Comment: It has to be a solution where the image can change from left to right without changing the markup, CSS only. As soon as you float the image, this method of centering no longer works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it using CSS3 transforms to take care of the vertical alignment of the name/title element.

I defined two classes, `.flipLeft` and `.flipRight` to control the placement of the name/title and the image elements.

I assumed that the image height will be as tall or taller than the height of the name/title, otherwise, things get more complicated.

The trick is to use the `text-align` property to place the image to the left or to the right of the parent block.

I then use absolute positioning to take the name/title element out of the content flow and pin it to the opposite edge of the parent block and adjust the `top` offset to 50% to get approximate vertical centering.

Finally, I use CSS3 transforms to adjust for the height of the name/title element.

**Note:** In the snippet below, scroll vertically to see both examples.

```css
.resumeStyleResumeTitleWrapper17 {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
}
.resumeStyleResumeTitle17 {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
.resumeStyleResumeTitleFontChange17 {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.resumeStyleResumeTitlePhotograph17 {
    border: 1px dotted yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.resumeStyleResumeTitlePhotographInner17 {
}
.name_details_photograph_preview_dimensions {
    max-height: 149px;
    max-width: 149px;
    display: block;
}
.flipLeft.resumeStyleResumeTitle17 {
    text-align: left;
}
.flipLeft .resumeStyleResumeTitleInner17 {
    border: 1px dotted yellow;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.flipRight.resumeStyleResumeTitle17 {
    text-align: right;
}
.flipRight .resumeStyleResumeTitleInner17 {
    border: 1px dotted yellow;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<h2>Flip Image to Left</h2>
<div class="resumeStyleResumeTitleWrapper17">
    <div class="resumeStyleResumeTitle17 flipLeft">
        <div class="resumeStyleResumeTitleInner17">
            <div class="resumeStyleResumeTitleFontChange17">User Name</div>
        </div>
        <div class="resumeStyleResumeTitlePhotograph17">
            <div class="resumeStyleResumeTitlePhotographInner17">
                <img class="name_details_photograph_preview_dimensions" src="http://placehold.it/140x100" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<h2>Flip Image to Right</h2>
<div class="resumeStyleResumeTitleWrapper17">
    <div class="resumeStyleResumeTitle17 flipRight">
        <div class="resumeStyleResumeTitleInner17">
            <div class="resumeStyleResumeTitleFontChange17">User Name</div>
        </div>
        <div class="resumeStyleResumeTitlePhotograph17">
            <div class="resumeStyleResumeTitlePhotographInner17">
                <img class="name_details_photograph_preview_dimensions" src="http://placehold.it/140x100" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't achieve it with `float` but I got the desired layout using `display: flex;`

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Aramil/be7kvx5o/2/)

```css
div.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: black;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
div.user_name {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    color: white;
    width: 50%;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
div.user_img {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

div.user_img > img {
    height: 100%!important;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="user_name">User Name</div>
    <div class="user_img">
        <img src="http://www.lessons4living.com/images/penclchk.gif"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show both versions with identical markup. (image left and right) Also, please explain how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Found a fix for this problem, update your HTML to following,

```
<div class="resumeStyleResumeTitleWrapper17">
    <div class="resumeStyleResumeTitle17">
        <div class="resumeStyleResumeTitlePhotograph17">
            <div class="resumeStyleResumeTitlePhotographInner17">
                <img class="name_details_photograph_preview_dimensions" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTWd99Qkjbg4ZVu-XHvaIo4LX1MittAmD0CvsiN6QcYeuv4XOQm" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="resumeStyleResumeTitleInner17">
            <div class="resumeStyleResumeTitleFontChange17">User Name</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In CSS,

```
.resumeStyleResumeTitleWrapper17 {
    width: 100%;
}

.resumeStyleResumeTitle17 {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    direction: ltr;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}

.resumeStyleResumeTitleInner17 {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    direction: ltr;
    max-height: 149px;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.resumeStyleResumeTitleFontChange17 {
    direction: ltr;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 100%;
}

.resumeStyleResumeTitlePhotograph17 {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  direction: ltr;
  max-height: 149px;
  max-width: 149px;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.resumeStyleResumeTitlePhotographInner17 {

}

.name_details_photograph_preview_dimensions {
    max-height: 149px;
    max-width: 149px;
}
.resumeStyleResumeTitle17:before{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -2px;
}
```

Basically I added a `.resumeStyleResumeTitle17:before` element which acts like a ghost element and takes the full height and allows each adjacent elements to be aligned by `display:inline-block` and now `vertical-align:middle` property is applicable.

Comment: Please remove all fixed heights. You currently have `height: 150px;`. The hight of the whole block may only depend on the (variable) height of the image. It has to work for images 60x60, but also 149x149, and 10x10, and ... You get it.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, this is to point you in the right direction, but it is obvious that you don't really understand what is going on. You have way too many div's there and really bad naming structure on the classes. Here is how I got it working somewhat in the direction you want without removing the divs and starting over (which is what I would do otherwise): ( Here is the live [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/be7kvx5o/) for it).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<style>
    .resumeStyleResumeTitleWrapper17 {
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
    background-color: #000;
    height:175px;
}

.resumeStyleResumeTitle17 {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    direction: ltr;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.resumeStyleResumeTitleInner17 {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    direction: ltr;
    float:right;
    width: 100%;
}

.resumeStyleResumeTitleFontChange17 {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float:right;
}

.resumeStyleResumeTitlePhotograph17 {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    direction: ltr;

}

.resumeStyleResumeTitlePhotographInner17 {
    float:left;
    height:175px;
}

.name_details_photograph_preview_dimensions {
    max-height: 149px;
    max-width: 149px;
}
</style>
<div class="resumeStyleResumeTitleWrapper17">
    <div class="resumeStyleResumeTitle17">
        <div class="resumeStyleResumeTitleInner17">
            <span class="resumeStyleResumeTitleFontChange17">User Name</span>
        </div>
        <div class="resumeStyleResumeTitlePhotograph17">
                <!-- image has max-height: 149px & max-width: 149px; assigned in the css file -->
                <img class="name_details_photograph_preview_dimensions" src="http://www.lessons4living.com/images/penclchk.gif" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, your code is not vertically centering the text. **That** is the challenging part.

Comment: @connexo ah I see. I'll update my answer if I add that back in.